Integral representation of conformal map on the upper half plane
It is a fact that there is a one to one correspondence between the space $M(k)$ of finite, signed Borel measures on $\mathbb{S}^1$ with total mass equal to $2$ and total variation equal to some $2 \leq k \leq 4$, and a certain class of univalent functions (injective, holomorphic functions or in other words a conformal map) on $\mathbb{D}$ (the so-called functions of bounded boundary rotation, $V_k$, with the normalization $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0)=1$), and this correspondence is given by the following integral representation (due to Paatero):
$$
f(z_0) = \int_{0}^{z_0} \exp\left[- \int_{\mathbb{S}^1} \log(1 - z \overline{\omega})) d \mu(\omega) \right]dz
$$
Another way of phrasing this is, that for functions defined by the above integral on the unit disk, such functions are guaranteed to be univalent as long as $\mu$ is a finite signed Borel measure on $\mathbb{S}^1$ satisfying $\mu(\mathbb{S}^1) = 2$ and $2 \leq \lvert \mu \rvert_{\text{TV}} \leq 4$.
I want to recover the corresponding representation formula for the upper half plane, which should be a standard exercise, but I could not find verification that the formula I obtained is valid since in the literature I have access to only the representation formula for the unit circle is given.
Suppose we choose the normalization $g(i) = 0, g'(i) = 1$ for the upper half plane, and then precompose the above $f$ by the Cayley transform $z \rightarrow \frac{z - i}{z+i}$.
To ensure the correct normalization one then multiplies by $2i$, and then making the change of variables $\zeta = \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ in the integral and pulling back $\mu$ to $\nu$ via the Borel isomorphism $(-\infty,+\infty] \rightarrow (0, 2 \pi]$ given by
$$
r \rightarrow \operatorname{arg}\left(\frac{r-i}{r+i}\right),
$$
(note here I am treating $S^1$ as $(0,2 \pi]$ for these spaces are the same up to Borel isomorphism) and $\mu$ as $\mu(t)$ defined on $(0,2 \pi]$, with the same properties i.e. $\mu(t)$ is a finite signed Borel measure with total mass $2$ and total variation between $2$ and $4$, and I am also replacing $\overline{\omega}$ with $\exp(-it)$), I obtain:
$$
g(w_0) = \int_{i}^{w_0} \exp\left[- \int_{(-\infty,+\infty]} \log\left(1 - \frac{z-i}{x-i}\right) d \nu(x) \right] dz,
$$
but the $+\infty$ part of the integral should be removable (I explain why I think so below) so that the correspondence should now be between the $V_k$ ($2 \leq k \leq 4$) functions with the normalization I chose on the upper-half plane and the finite signed Borel measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R} = (-\infty,+\infty)$, satisfying $2 \leq \lvert \nu \restriction \mathbb{R} \rvert_{\text{TV}} + |2 - \nu(\mathbb{R})| \leq 4$.
In other words, I think we should be able to remove the $+\infty$ part in the above integral representation as long as our $\nu $ (defined on $\mathbb{R}$), satisfies the above condition so the correspondence between these functions and $V_k$ still holds, because the integrand against $\nu(x)$ vanishes at $x = +\infty$ given we use a branch of $\log$ for which $\log(1) = 0$ , and this should always be possible because for any fixed $z$, $1 - \frac{z-i}{x-i}$ maps a whole simply connected open neighbourhood of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ (here the closure is taken in the Riemann sphere), to a simply connected domain in $\mathbb{C}$ avoiding zero and containing $1$, where such a branch of $\log$ can be defined. Moreover any two such branches differ by $2 n \pi i$ for some integer $n$, and since integrating this against $\nu(x)$ on $(-\infty,+\infty]$ gives $4n \pi i$, the $\exp$ outside means that we can choose any branch of $\log$ when evaluating this integral.
All in all this should yield that:
For a function defined for $w_0 \in \mathbb{H}$ by:
$$
g(w_0) = \int_{i}^{w_0} \exp\left[- \int_{\mathbb{R}} \log\left(1 - \frac{z-i}{x-i}\right) d \nu(x) \right] dz,
$$
where $\log$ is always chosen so that $\log(1) = 0$, $g$ is univalent in $\mathbb{H}$ as long as $\nu$ is a finite signed Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying:
$2 \leq \lvert \nu \rvert_{\text{TV}} + |2 - \nu(\mathbb{R})| \leq 4$, because this condition implies that $\nu$ extends to a finite signed Borel measure on $(-\infty,+\infty]$, with total mass $2$ and total variation between $2$ and $4$, then the above procedure can be run backwards and we will obtain a function in $V_k$ ($2 \leq k \leq 4$) defined on $\mathbb{D}$, and such functions are known to be univalent.
$\textbf{My question/concern}$: It feels like something is wrong here, although overall I am not entirely convinced this is true yet, because e.g. this seems reminiscent of the Schwarz-Christoffel formula for the upper half plane when a prevertex is chosen to be $\infty$, indeed I believe my formula and its condition in the upper-half plane revert back to the Schwarz-Christoffel formula, the condition on $\nu$ in this (polygonal) case should just be saying that if a full-turn is not made before reaching the vertex (if any) corresponding to the prevertex at $\infty$, then it is made (and not overshot or undershot) when the prevertex at $\infty$ is reached.
Still the overall conclusion seems erroneous to me, because it feels like somehow some information has been lost. I would greatly appreciate anyone else's opinion on this.
